Movie about life after death from all timezones with historic figures & steampunk boat?
I'm trying to find this movie about:
A male character who's the star of the movie. He dies 'in real life' and then passes to the next life. The next life is some sort of world were all kinds of people from all timezones come together. It's like their second chance?
I don't remember the goal/purpose of movie/male character.
Specific items I remember from the movie:

It's from the year 2000+
It was in color, english spoken (dutch subtitles).
In the next life everybody has this bracelet to obtain food. The male character is the only one who doesn't have a bracelet.
The male character dies another 2 or 3 times in the afterlife world & gets ressurected each time.
There is, not 100% sure, a magical person with a blue face (Nooo... not avatar) & white robes which ressurects the male character, everytime.
There is some old steampunk-like boat that floats on the river, few scene's are taken on the boat aswell.
The movie was pretty long, I would say even 3+ hours.
There is some kind of army (with swords I believe not guns, since it's an army from an older era) trying to kill the male character.
There are other historical figures that run around in the afterlife world
Not a 100% sure, but I believe you cannot escape the world either. It's somewhat of a closed world?


Related (though it was never approved and your Q is much more detailed)

You're looking for Riverworld from 2010.

Riverworld is a television film released on the Syfy channel on April 18, 2010. Based on the Riverworld books by Philip José Farmer, the made-for-TV film is a reboot of the aborted Sci-Fi Channel Riverworld television series, of which only the pilot episode was produced.
War reporter Matt Ellman is in Singapore with his girlfriend Jessie, to whom he is about to propose marriage. Unfortunately, before he proposes, both of them are killed in a terrorist attack by a suicide bomber. Afterwards, they find themselves on a strange planet called Riverworld, where everyone who has ever lived on Earth has been reborn along the banks of a seemingly endless river. Riverworld functions as a sort of purgatory for deceased human beings to get a second chance. In this world, Matt finds several of his deceased friends as well as historical figures, some of whom are his allies and others who are antagonistic.

It contains everything you said (including the blue-faced "Caretaker") and is about 3 hours long. Here's the trailer:




Yes I am looking for this. Didn't think it would be from 2010 O.o
